# How to disable CSS imports in JSPM / SystemJS

Tags: angular-material, jspm, systemjs

My issue is JSPM / SystemJS manually inserting CSS dependencies (namely *Angular Material's* CSS) when I have a different pipeline for those (Gulp + SASS).

**How can I tell JSPM to not import CSS files or interpret CSS dependencies in any way?** I found only this discussion - https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/791 - but it did not help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that JSPM prefers *local package overrides* rather than turning off CSS features completely.

The culprit of my original issue is Angular Material's [`package.json`](https://github.com/angular/bower-material/blob/master/package.json), which contains the following JSPM configuration:

```
"shim": {
    "angular-material": {
        "deps": [ "./angular-material.css!" ]
      }
}
```

So what really solved my issue was to override that configuration:

```
jspm install angular-material -o '{ shim: {} }'
```