# How to get rid off multiple style tags inserted to head by AngularJS Material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

AngularJS Material inserts multiple (around 30) style tags with `md-theme-style` attribute. I guess it's some kind of performance tuning but I would rather do it myself - I don't need an external framework to pollute my HTML in this nasty way. Any thoughts on how to get rid of the style tags?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if it is worth the hassle.  Please back-up your work, I have not tested any of this:

Angular-material includes some default theme css as a const variable in JavaScript. You can view this code in `angular-material.js` at the bottom starting with the line:

```
angular.module("material.core").constant("$MD_THEME_CSS"...
```

When loaded into your browser this adds lots of css style tags dynamically to the page document. To disable them you will need to recompile angular-material yourself using the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/material.git
```

Then install dependancies:

```
cd material
npm install
```

Then go to gulp/util.js and change line `53` from:

```
var jsProcess = series(jsBuildStream, themeBuildStream() )
```

to be:

```
var jsProcess = series(jsBuildStream)
```

Then run the build process:

```
gulp build
```

This question gives more detail:
[How to get rid off Angular Material extra styles and CSS linked by it 'forcefully'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466779/how-to-get-rid-off-angular-material-extra-styles-and-css-linked-by-it-forcefull)

Comment: the same issue was occurred for me, iam using grunt instead of gulp, how can i remove those tags with grunt @Jared Hooper

Answer (score 3):

[Direct from the angular material docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/04_multiple_themes)

Lazy Generate Themes

By default, every theme is generated when defined. You can disable this in the configuration section using the `$mdThemingProvider`

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
        //disable theme generation
        $mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true);
    });
```

Here's the exact syntax I used, and it worked like a champ. (Important to note this didn't break any style for us, either):

```
.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true);
}])
```

It may also be useful to know this seems to be a standard for angular. I had to turn the animations down too. By default they were animating pretty much everything.

Comment: For me this still created some, ``<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>`` but much less than before, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers the question, but to completely remove all of the `<style/>` elements from the top of the page, I did the following:

```
angular.module( 'myApp', ['ngMaterial'] )
   .config( function( $mdThemingProvider, $provide ) {
       $mdThemingProvider.theme('myTheme')
           .primaryPalette('blue')
           .accentPalette('green')
           .warnPalette('yellow');
       $mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true);
       $provide.value('themingProvider', $mdThemingProvider);
    });
```

and this successfully removed all the elements.

Now, when I *want* them generated, I call this within the main controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', function( themingProvider ){
    themingProvider.reload('myTheme'); 
    // pretty sure it's themingProvider.generateTheme('myTheme')
    // but I ended up refactoring this workaround out, anyway.
});
```

The answer is based on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28602668/3872894)