# Stop angular-material from injecting styles into the head tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Is there a way to prevent angular-material from injecting theme css into the head tag? I am not sure how to stop this from happening.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238743/how-to-get-rid-off-multiple-style-tags-inserted-to-head-by-angular-material