# Duplicated styles on head and a lot of <style> elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material2

I'm quite happy with angular-material2 components but there are some weird behaviors that I don't understand and they don't have a proper documentation especially for teeming and customizing their components.

My project looks like:

```
.src
  --app
    --components
      --login-component
           login-component.html
           login-component.scss
           login-component.js
      --login-component
            home-component.html
            home-component.scss
            home-component.js
       --and so on ...
    app.component.html
    app.component.scss
    app.component.ts
    app.module.ts
    app.routing.ts
    --assets
    --environments
    --scss
      styles.scss
      _material2-theme.scss
      _variables-scss
      _utilities.scss
      _reset.scss
   favicon
   index.html
   and so on ....
```

In angular-cli.json I have modified the styles to look at scss/style.scss

```
...
"styles": [
        "scss/styles.scss"
      ]
...
```

the _material2-theme.scss looks like:

```
//////////////////////* THEMES */ Custom Blue Theme*/
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-blue, A200, A100, A400);
$app-theme:   mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent);
@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);

/*default palette forground/background*/
$light-foreground-palette: map-get($app-theme, foreground);
$light-background-palette: map-get($app-theme, background);

$primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);
$accent: map-get($app-theme, accent);
```

and inside of style.scss I am importing everything to be compiled with scss cli compiler

```
//////////////////////* CUSTOM */
@import "_material2-theme.scss";
@import "_reset.scss";
@import "_utilities.scss";
 //////////////////////* COMPONENTS */
 @import "~app/components/login/login.component.scss";
```

**My question is after the scss is compiled we have in html head many style tags some of them duplicated and look like**:

[image]

Everything seems to be compiled in one style that is added in head(tha one that has type attribute) and and after that each scss component splited in each css component with its separate style in head, and that is very weird. I am doing something wrong or is just tha way is working material2?

Comment: Please don't combine singleline and multiline comments together. **It just looks weird.** BTW, you don't need to include `mat-core` again in your `material-theme` file.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure it's intentional behaviour in order for dynamic theming to work?

Comment: @Edric yeah but those comments will not help me to solve my problem and the mat-core() need to be added whan a custom theme is used how is described in material2 : https://material.angular.io/guide/theming. I really don't know is this is a intentional behavior or not .... just trying to find an answer .

Comment: can you setup a demo github repo and ask a specific question?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I think you can initiate any small project and include angular material and the result will be the same

Comment: @mcmwhfy, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48276350/2545680)

Comment: @mcmwhfy, how come the answer by SandipPatel is correct? and why the bounty is 150 instead of 300?

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com no answer is correct, I didn't picked one, but the stackoverflow splited my points into the most voted answers which is shit !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is caused by `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` defined for material components.

First, you **don't need** to add styles for components to the global styles `"scss/styles.scss"`:

```
//////////////////////* COMPONENTS */
@import "~app/components/login/login.component.scss";
```

If you do that, besides your styles getting duplicated you will lose style encapsulation because styles added for `components/login/login.component.scss` will become global.

Now, to the question **why there are many `style` elements**. When you use `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`, and it's a default view encapsulation mode, Angular will put each component's style into its own `style` tag and add attribute to elements inside a component template. In material all components use emulated encapsulation mode so for each component the `style` tag is added.

If you add `@Component({..., encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native })` for your components, you will see the `style` for your components will be removed.

[Here is the logic](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/04dd9713f090ae7a9710b08b6a23b3619112fb3d/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.ts#L43) that adds the `style` tag:

```
export class DomSharedStylesHost extends SharedStylesHost implements OnDestroy {
  ...
  private _addStylesToHost(styles: Set<string>, host: Node): void {
    styles.forEach((style: string) => {
      const styleEl = this._doc.createElement('style');  <--- creates a style element
      styleEl.textContent = style;
      this._styleNodes.add(host.appendChild(styleEl));
    });
  }
```

Comment: your answer should be awarded but, yeah .. nice stackoverflow actions ... now I saw your answer and I cannot take back or reapply my points :|

Comment: @mcmwhfy, ah, I see, honestly I didn't know about such policy on stackoverflow. Thanks for accepting my answer then.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95039/what-happens-when-bounty-gets-expired

Answer (score 2):

In Material design for Angular the stylesheet is split into:

- style - margins, paddings etcetera that is linked from the component
- theme - mostly colors that is build using the theme scss
- typography - fonts & font properties that is built using the typography scss

This causes similar selectors, but with different properties inside.

I think it is the live development server that comes with angular cli or webpack that loads css dynamically which causes duplication of style tags. I believe this is not happening in a production build.

PS. Strange of you to add _reset.scss after anything else.

Comment: that reset is actually kind of normalizer of some elements like p{margin:0; padding: 0;} and stuff like that

Comment: Thats why it is usually the first thing on the page if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is due to having separate styles for each component.
This issue is similar to what's there in a [`ngularjs-material`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466779/how-to-get-rid-off-angular-material-extra-styles-and-css-linked-by-it-forcefull) as well.

**`Angular-material`** includes some default theme **css** as a const variable in JavaScript.

You can read a more on this issue , 
**[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466779/how-to-get-rid-off-angular-material-extra-styles-and-css-linked-by-it-forcefull`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466779/how-to-get-rid-off-angular-material-extra-styles-and-css-linked-by-it-forcefull)**

Answer (score 0):

In development, the angular cli or webpack compiles every css/scss files from each component to a style tag in the HTML page.

ie, in your case: login-component.scss, home-component.scss each will be loaded inside seperate style tags in the HTML page.

All these will be compiled into a single css file and will be linked in index.html in production conf.

*So I too think its the way angular works!*

Currently I see that there is only one file generated in production build  <kbd>ng build --prod</kbd>  .

Comment: not really sure is like that, anyway I need a way to have just one style in head in which are all scss files compiled.

Comment: If you need to have a single file only in development configuration also, you could add a gulp task for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `style` tag in your head may be your every `component` is linked with some external different css Or you have written internal css at related HTML page.

If you want that there is only one `style` tag throughout application then in that case you have to write all style in single file.

Comment: Hey, your answer is not correct and doesn't seem to be eligible for the bounty it received.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com : how you know my answer is not correct? Have you tried? Give me proof of wrong answer.

Comment: He does not have to prove you are wrong. You have to prove you are right.